# How to assign a property a type inside an object constant in TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, pixi.js

Learning TypeScript and I'm wondering if there's an easy in-line way to signify the type inside an object constant when TypeScript doesn't infer the property type correctly?

Error Message:

```
Type '{ align: string; fontWeight: string; dropShadow: boolean; dropShadowAlpha: number; wordWrap: boolean; fill: string[]; }' is not assignable to type 'TextStyle | Partial<ITextStyle> | undefined'.
  Type '{ align: string; fontWeight: string; dropShadow: boolean; dropShadowAlpha: number; wordWrap: boolean; fill: string[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<ITextStyle>'.
    Types of property 'align' are incompatible.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'TextStyleAlign | undefined'.ts(2322)
```

Got this error message before I replaced the original align and fontWeight values with textStyleAlign and textStyleFontWeight.

How I created this example:

```
yarn create react-app app-name --template typescript
cd app-name
yarn add pixi.js
yarn add @inlet/react-pixi
```

App.tsx

```
import { Stage, Text} from '@inlet/react-pixi';
import type { TextStyleAlign, TextStyleFontWeight } from '@pixi/text';

const textStyleAlign : TextStyleAlign = 'center';
const textStyleFontWeight : TextStyleFontWeight = '900';

const textStyle = {
  align: textStyleAlign,
  // align: 'center',   // <- why can't I put this instead?
  fontWeight: textStyleFontWeight,
  // fontWeight: '900', // <- same here
  dropShadow: true,
  dropShadowAlpha: 0.6,
  wordWrap: true,
  fill: ["white", "#cccccc"]
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Stage>
      <Text
        text={`Hi World`}
        style={textStyle}
      />
    </Stage>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey by taking a look at the docs you need to pass a TextStyle instance like this:

```
const textStyle = new TextStyle({
  align: "center",
  fontWeight: "900",
  dropShadow: true,
  dropShadowAlpha: 0.6,
  wordWrap: true,
  fill: ["white", "#cccccc"]
});
```

If you don't want to create that instance you can do this:

```
import { ITextStyle, TextStyle } from "pixi.js";

// The style prop also takes a Partial of ITextStyle so by typing the const like that you would achieve the typing correctly
const textStyle: Partial<ITextStyle> = {
  align: "center",
  fontWeight: "900",
  dropShadow: true,
  dropShadowAlpha: 0.6,
  wordWrap: true,
  fill: ["white", "#cccccc"]
};
```

If you want to make it like the code you posted then you can use the as type assertion like this

```
const textStyle = {
  align: "center" as TextStyleAlign,
  fontWeight: "900" as TextStyleFontWeight,
  dropShadow: true,
  dropShadowAlpha: 0.6,
  wordWrap: true,
  fill: ["white", "#cccccc"]
};
```

If you pass any of those 3 methods you won't have type problems:

```
<Text text="Hi World" style={textStyle} />
```

I noticed that by checking the style prop o the Text component:

```
style?: TextStyle | Partial<ITextStyle> | undefined
```

So basically all the typing done above will work.

Check this sandbox to look the functional code: https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-platform-zzvnb

Comment: Type Assertion with the 'as' keyword is perfect for this example. Thank you. Figured it would be something simple that I overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

Because `align` has only three type: 'left', 'center' or 'right': https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.TextStyle.html#align

So if you want to use align, you need to make sure it has these types. Not string with value `center`. You can use `TextStyleAlign` to declare the type as you do. Or `const textStyleAlign : 'center' = 'center';`.

If you don't want declare type like this. You can use `new TextStyle()`: https://reactpixi.org/components/text

```
style={
  new TextStyle({
    align: 'center',
    ...
  })
}
```

Comment: This is the correct explanation. I cannot edit the answer at the moment, but I would add that, because the `const textStyle` object is not explicitly typed, nor is the `align` property explicitly typed, the `align` property is being interpreted as a type of `string` which is not assignable to `'left'`, `'center'`, or `'right'`; as an example, `'foo'` is also a `string`.